# mysql.sock error in WordPress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, memory

I've one website built using WordPress and it sometimes throw an error like:

> Warning: mysql_connect(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through
>   socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in
>   .../public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1372

When I made search for this issue, all answers justifying that this is problem from server side and not in coding. So I've contacted the server support team and they answered that it is an issue caused by memory use and answered "**MySQL processes are using a lot of memory and getting OOM kills from the node**"

So can anyone please tell me that what should I do to solve the issue, I asked server support team to increase memory size the they denied.

Comment: You're not going to like it but you might need to switch hosts. OOM can sometimes be solved by adding RAM but usually that's just a stopgap. Odds are your host has dozens or possibly hundreds of sites on the single box and coupled with the very common botnet attacks the server is just being flooded with requests. There's probably only a handful of sites on the box causing the problem so your host should be auditing traffic and finding ways to mitigate the problem. They should also be transparent to you with this. If they are not, jump ship.

Comment: Thank you @ChrisHaas for your response. So can I assume that the issue is caused due to server and not because of SQL queries fired by WordPress code?

Comment: The likelihood of this being a core WP related issue without it flaring up across the internet and making news everywhere is very small. The possibility, albeit small, of a bad plugin exists so I'd recommend doing due diligence and just checking each's support page on WP to make sure no one else is reporting it. There might be some weird edge case you are encountering. However, if I were to place bets I'd say that this is a server issue and not related directly to WP or any of the queries that WP generates.